# What is the memory requirement of an enum in cpp?

Tags: c++, memory, enums

I am creating a large scale simulation with many parts , I am using an enum to distinguish between the multiple parts. I would like to know what the memory cost of using an enum is ,as I want to keep the space taken up by the part to a minimum .

Is it better to use uint8_t instead of an enum ?

Comment: Typical C compilers allocate the smallest integer size. You can always check sizeof( myenum ) ...

Comment: You can specify the integer type of the enum (`enum foo : uint8_t {}`)

Comment: Reminder:  `enum` is a **signed** integer by default.

Comment: @lorro Is it the same in cpp too  ?

Comment: @Pubby thanks . That solves the question I guess. Add as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews signed integer of what size ? Does what you say over ride what Pubby has posted ?

Comment: The default size of an `enum` is the smallest `signed int` that can contain the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++ (any version), the underlying type of an enumeration is `int` by default, unless every enumerator value cannot be represented as an `int`.
In this case, an implementation-defined type is used (one large enough to represent every enumerator value). Note that the size of `int` depends on your machine. It might be 16 bits, but is probably 32 bits (even on 64-bit machines). Ultimately, it is decided by the compiler.

Since C++11, you can specify the underlying type when declaring the enumeration, using the following form :

```
enum name : underlying_type { ... };

// For example
enum MySmallEnum : char { ... };
```

Source : [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

[In C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum), it seems like it obeys the same rule as in C++ (before C++11).